# Capybara: "controller" is nil?

Tags: rspec, capybara

Test:

```
it "works" do
      controller.stub!(:closest_campus).and_return(@location)
      visit "/locations"
end
```

Result:

```
An expectation of :closest_campus was set on nil
```

I've never had this warning in Rspec before, but it's now showing with Capybara. Any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

It's because @location is nil so it warns that you explicitly stub a method to return nil. Which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Sorry to confuse. @location is set in before(:each) and is available.